# hibernate- composite key configuration

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables with parent/child relation. Child have a table with two columns. 
Originally Primary key value of child table was same as parent tables Primary key value. 
I have defined it in child table’s hbm like this..

```
<id name="c1" type="int">
    <column name="column1"/>
    <generator class="foreign"/>
        <param name="property">column1</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Now second column ( defined as below ) in Child table is also part of primary key.

```
<many-to-one name="c2" class="com.Column2" fetch="select">
    <column name="column2" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

So I have to make a composite-id in hbm and basically have these both columns define in it, but composit-id probably doesn’t support generator id something like what I am trying to do

```
<composite-id>
    <key-many-to-one name="c1" column="column1"/>
    <key-many-to-one name="c2" column="column2"/>
</composite-id>
```

But it seems composite-id doesn’t support auto-generated(first1) type of column. So my question is how to for a composit-id in hbm file with one column using generator class and one in “many-to-one” mapping…

Comment: I don't know why my hbm file snippets never show on this site...anybody?

Comment: Basically, what I want to achieve is, I have cascade="all" between parent/child tables. Parent's key is one of the primary keys in child table but parent/child has one-to-many relationship so "generated key" in child table is not unique. Uniqueness is defined by compbnation of columns in child table which I can't define because composite-key in child table doesn't support generated key. As a result when just generated key is Id, if cascading insert tries to insert more than one records of same generated key in child table then hibernate throws "noUniqueObject" exception...anyone?