# Foreign Key Hibernate Configuration

Tags: database, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

i'm trying to use hibernate with an existing mysql db using Eclipse.

I've succeeded mapping tables to classes and executing some query. 
But i have  a problem with a one to many relation.

I have the table "CARATTERISTICHE" (attributes) which is, in fact, a tree, described by a join table "VALORI" (values): "fk_child" "fk_parent".

I would like that the class Caratteristica had a field "children" with type `List<Caratteristica>`, where the children should be the join with CARATTERISTICA and VALORI.

My first attempt was to create a pojo Caratteristica and let eclipse generate the configurations file of hibernate.

That doesn't work because when I launch getChildren all i got is the same object (i.e. every node is his father, which is false in my db).

This is an excerpt of the generated xml:

```
<class name="model.Caratteristica" table="caratteristiche">
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="ID"/>
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <set access="field" lazy="true" name="children"
   sort="unsorted" table="valori">
   <key>
    <column name="id"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="model.Caratteristica"/>
  </set>
```

Note that if change the column key from id to fk_child he can't find fk_child in table "CARATTERISTICHE" (but it should look in VALORI, right?)

I've also tried to generate pojos from tables but it's worse..
Maybe i've got this problem [hibernate- composite key configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587143/hibernate-composite-key-configuration) but.. it's my first time I use hibernate, I'm really lost!

Comment: What's wrong with the generating POJOs and DAOs from the db?

Comment: @RomanC I've followed this http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables but i get this error org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Could not bind factory to JNDI

Comment: Why did you bind the factory to JNDI?

Comment: This looks like more nice looking [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is a bit strange.

Either you have a complete tree structure, i. e. a 1 : n relation between parents and children. Then you do not need the join table VALORI. In CARATTERISTICHE you just define a column parentId, which contains the id of the parent row. In your mapping you give this new column as the key tag: `<key> <column name="parentId"/>  </key>`

Or you have an m : n relation between parents and children, which is defined by the join table VALORI. The tree structure can be defined as a special case with the m : n relation, but other structures are also possible. Then you must use the `<many-to-many>` tag (instead of one-to-many). The `<many-to-many>` tag contains the `column` attribute, which allows to specify the name of the corresponding foreign key in the other table.